# Two Way binding to a Dependency Property in a User Control and call a method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I know, title is a little confusing so let me explain. I have a user control that has a dependency property. I access this dependency property with a regular property called Input. In my view model I also have a property called Input. I have these two properties bound together in XAML using two-way binding as shown below:

```
<uc:rdtDisplay x:Name="rdtDisplay" Input="{Binding Input, Mode=TwoWay}" Line1="{Binding myRdt.Line1}" Line2="{Binding myRdt.Line2}" Height="175" Width="99"  Canvas.Left="627" Canvas.Top="10"/>
```

Okay in my view model, I call a method whenever the value of Input is changed as shown in my property:

```
public string Input
        {
            get
            {
                return input;
            }
            set
            {
                input = value;
                InputChanged();
            }
        }
```

The problem with this is that when I set the value of Input in my view model it only updates the value of the variable input as per my setter in my property. How can I get this to update back to the dependency property in the user control? If I leave the code `input = value;` out then I get a compilation error.

I need something like this:

```
public string Input
            {
                get
                {
                    return UserControl.Input;
                }
                set
                {
                    UserControl.Input = value;
                    InputChanged();
                }
            }
```

If I make the Input property in my view model look like this:

```
public string Input
        {
            get; set;
        }
```

then it works, however, I am unable to call the InputChanged() method that I need to call when the Property is changed. All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: The Input property should be bound to the DependencyProperty.  It appears you're doing this, but I can't understand why it isn't working.  You wouldn't happen to have built a ViewModel for your UserControl, did you?  Like creating a rdtDisplayViewModel that you use inside of the UserControl to perform all your UI work?  Something tells me you've gone and done this....

Comment: I have some code in the code behind of my user control, but not a separate view model.

Comment: For two way to work, your CLR Input property should use some change notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `ViewModel`

```
public class Sample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string input = string.Empty;
    public string Input
    {
        get
        {
            return input;
        }
        set
        {
            input = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Input");
            InputChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

}
```

In your case, you can do it in the code behind of your usercontrol

Comment: No, DO NOT DO THIS in "code behind of usercontrol"! Do this in your viewmodel. To be refactory safe inherit from Microsoft.Practices.Prism.ViewModel.NotificationObject  and in the setter after InputChanged(); add RaisePropertyChanged(() => Input);

Comment: please edit your answer by removing the last sentence regarding the code behind, see my comment.

Comment: It is not at all mandatory that he should create a viewmodel. Since he has already mentioned that he doesn't have a viewmodel, I suggested this. If he was following MVVM, what you suggested was right.

Comment: I disagree. It ist clear, that he is following the mvvm Pattern, because the question is tagged as MVVM and ProgrammingDude wrote: 'in my **view model**, I call a method'

Comment: Your answer is correct and helped me out, but gRex was right. I had to do it in my viewModel so that the value that I set in my viewModel was reflected back to my user control.